# Speeding up a SQL query that must compute Euclidean Distance

Tags: sql, sql-server, euclidean-distance

I have a rather complex and long sql query.  Essential I want the row with the smallest euclidean distance in the table from some given value.  The catch is the vector has 27 dimensions so it is a rather expensive calculation and then it needs to be done on all columns.

I've considering adding an alternate table that each row maps to and this table will be a bucket.  Pre determined values and then I would use the triangle inequality to limit how many rows I have to perform the calculation.

Another is making the columns I need to perform the calculations with indexs, but I don't know how much that will help.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: An immediate optimization when finding smallest euclidean distance is to not take the square root.  Work on distance-squared.  Might not be a significant factor on a 27-dimensional vector, though.

Comment: If this value is queried multiple times, can't the value be calculated on insert or update and stored in a new column?  From a DB perspective, this would make more sense.  Your new query would simply look at that new column and return quickly.

Comment: @paddy Yeah, I considered this and will add it later but I doubt it will make a significant difference.

Comment: @ps2goat.  It is very unlikely the exactly same value will be queried twice.  There are 256^27 distinct values the query argument can take on.  So quite a bit.

Comment: It might be worth breaking out a custom CLR datatype here. You could take a look at how the geometry type is implemented for 2-space and try to extend it to your 27-space.